# Convert NVARCHAR to DATE SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble converting this nvarchar to date: I want to convert '2021-02-01 00:00:00.0000000' nvarchar to 2021-02-01 date

```
   DECLARE @var nvarchar(255) = '2021-02-01 00:00:00.0000000'
   CONVERT(date, @var, 103)
```

I have used this convert function but I'm getting:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

error. Any help on how to solve this problem?

Comment: If you check the docs, `103` does not match the format of the input string. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles why did you pick that number?

Answer (score 2):

Try `120` instead of `103`. `103` expects a string in the format `d/m/y`.

```
DECLARE @var nvarchar(255) = '2021-02-01 00:00:00.0000000';
SELECT CONVERT(date, @var, 120);
```

Result ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b9162a5c4d29c681273e503a7a2bf37c)):

```
2021-02-01
```

Also:

- Why `nvarchar`? Dates don't need to support Unicode characters.
- Try to get the source to correct the format to a standard, unambiguous format, like:

  ```
    yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn
    yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn
  ```

Much more on dates: [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates)

Answer (score 0):

You can `CAST` that format directly to a `DATE` or `DATETIME2` type.

```
DECLARE @var nvarchar(255) = '2021-02-01 00:00:00.0000000'
DECLARE @date date = CAST(@var AS DATE);

SELECT @var as var, @date as [date];
```

Or even [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) it without a format number.

```
DECLARE @var nvarchar(255) = '2021-02-01 00:00:00.0000000'
DECLARE @datetime2 datetime2 = CONVERT(DATETIME2, @var);

SELECT @var as var, @datetime2 as [datetime2];
```

But to `CAST` or `CONVERT` it to a `DATETIME`, then it needs to be truncated.
The default format number is 121 *(ODBC canonical with milliseconds)*

```
DECLARE @var nvarchar(255) = '2021-02-01 00:00:00.0000000'
DECLARE @datetime datetime = CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(@var, 23), 121);

SELECT @var as var, @datetime as [datetime];
```